# Could not get any response in postman version 5.5.0

Tags: postman

I installed postman's native app in my desktop(Postman version 5.5.0). Now when I send simple soap request, "**Could not get any response**" message is shown. The same request when sent in my previous postman chrome extension I get the expected response. Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the request you have made? please share minimum input for debugging

Comment: I am sending a POST request with soap body and few headers along.

Comment: Can you provide more information about the request please? The URL, Headers, Message Body etc? Also screenshots of Postman showing the error would be useful. Hard to help without these basic details.

Comment: I found an open github issue for 5.5: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3963

Answer (score 0):

What i have done it is first of all install postman.

Later go to task manager once u open the app, click on Postman on the task manager, and click on finish task.

Later go to your icon desktop and click on it another time. Now it will work properly and launch without any probblem. It works with me with a W8.0